# Convex figure is equal to intersection of supporting half planes

Tags: geometry

> Prove that for any closed, convex, figure $\mathcal{F}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $$\mathcal{F} = \bigcap_{H \supset \mathcal{F}} H$$ where $H$ is any supporting half plane of $\mathcal{F}$.

We know that $$\mathcal{F} \subset \bigcap_{H \supset \mathcal{F}} H$$ since $H \supset \mathcal{F}$. But I am wondering how to show the reverse inclusion. That is, how do we show that $$\mathcal{F} \supset \bigcap_{H \supset \mathcal{F}} H?$$

Also, is a supporting line to a convex figure just a tangent line?

Comment: For the second question: what would your definition of a tangent line to the corner of a square be?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Good point. That makes sense now. I think my problem can be generalized for any convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: It is true that the intersection of a closed convex set with a supporting line is either a point, a closed segment, a closed half-line or the whole line (because intersection of closed convex sets is convex and closed and there is not much coice in $\Bbb R$ for that).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I am taking the intersection of all supporting half planes of $\mathbb{F}$ that contain $\mathbb{F}$.